# Is there a name for smoothed maximum value function?

Tags: statistics, optimization, terminology

I have several arrays that look something like this: [Spectrum Plot](http://images.batronix.com/products/spectrum-analyzer/DSA815/screen-color-trace.jpg).  Think gaussian curves, but shorter and with lots of noise.

I've been comparing values for the sake of *peak detection*.  Through experimentation, I've modified the comparison to be the average of `x` number of values around (and including) the maximum value.

I'm really sorry I can't figure out the Math Jax thing, but here's a rough translation of my c# code:

```
double[]     trace =      GetSpectrum();
double[]     baseline =   GetAverageOfAllTraces();
List<double> deviations = GetStandardDeviationOfEachTrace();

for (int i = 1; i < baseline.Length; i++)
    baseline[i] = (baseline[i] + baseline[i - 1]) / 2) + deviations.Average();

int index = trace.IndexOf(trace.Max());
int x = 2;
double maximum = trace.SubArray(index - x, index + x).Average();
if (maximum > baseline[index])
    bool validPeak = true;
```

If someone wants to translate, I'd be very grateful.

$$
average(maxIndex-2, maxIndex+2) > average(all) + stddev(all)
$$

I've started calling this a *smoothed maximum*, but is there a name for what I'm doing?

Additionally, if there's some term for what I'm doing entirely and I'm just reinventing the wheel here, that would also be nice to know.